# Adding Application Claims from User Flow into AAD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

This is the Azure B2C User Flow’s Application claims, where I can tick the Email Addresses and save it.
[UserFlow Application Claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr3JC.png)

How can I do this in custom policy? I am trying to add Multi-Tenant login to AAD B2C via custom policies and I need to select this ‘Email Addresses’ in the Application Claims from User Flow.
How can I select or activate this same ‘Email Addresses’ in custom policy XML files?

So far I tried adding  -->> OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" <<--  to the technical profiles, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim you want is "preferred_username".

Try to add `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />`.

Comment: The error went away, but I've gotten another error from my web app:
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)

Also I tested a run on a web app using "https://jwt.ms/, it also has this error:
AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact administrator of the site you are trying to access.

Anything I need to double check on? do I need to add preferred username output claim into SignUpOrSignin.xml?

Comment: @BCdeve I'm not sure. The information is too little and it's related to a new issue. It's recommended to add a new post with details. If my answer is helpful to the original issue in this post, you can mark it as accepted. If you are happy to mark correct answer , others are more happy to help you:)

Comment: Thanks Allen, do you know which OutputClaim should I implement to the file for Facebook, Twitter and Google? Adding <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" will still give me the error "Email Addresses should be enabled in "Application Claims".

Comment: @BCdeve Sorry I'm not familiar with the social idps you mentioned. It's recommended to add a new post so that more people can see your question.